# Objective-C category for styling

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

What is the best way to create re-usable styling for UI objects for iOS app?

E.g. I want to use the same style for each UITextField - top/bottom line and thinking about creating a category to provide the styling and simply apply it in View Controller.

Is there any better solution to do this?

**UITextField+TextFieldStyler.m**

```
- (void)addTopBorderWithColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    CGRect topBorderFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, 1.0);
    UIView *topBorder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:topBorderFrame];
    topBorder.backgroundColor = color;

    [self addSubview:topBorder];
}
```

**PXRLoginViewController.m**

```
[self.nameFIeld addTopBorderWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.passwordField addTopBorderWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Comment: You could use [UIAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for basic appearance modification. For what you're trying to do, a category is just fine. Although I must ask why you're adding a view to the text field to add a border. If you merely wish to add a border to the text field, you should modify the border width and border color properties  on the text field's layer.

Comment: Will look over UIAppearance, thank you. Is it possible to add only top border to a view (not all of them) via layer?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't initially see that's what you were trying to do. That way is just fine.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Thank you for your help. I'm trying to find the best way to include re-usable styling in my app and categories (maybe of UIView instead) seems to work for me, but I'm not sure if it's the best practice.

Comment: You should be alright. One thing I can think of though would be if you want to be able to change the color (or something) of the border after adding it. You wouldn't want to continue calling the add... method. In these kinds of cases, you'd want to create a subclass of UITextField and give it a top border property. From there, you'd be free to modify the added view on the fly via textFieldInstance.topBorder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the approach you are using is completely fine. It's also used by Apple itself for the same use cases, looking at the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)

> **Note:** Cocoa and Cocoa Touch include a variety of categories for some
> of the primary framework classes.
>
> The string-drawing functionality
> mentioned in the introduction to this chapter is in fact already
> provided for NSString by the NSStringDrawing category for OS X, which
> includes the drawAtPoint:withAttributes: and
> drawInRect:withAttributes: methods. For iOS, the UIStringDrawing
> category includes methods such as drawAtPoint:withFont: and
> drawInRect:withFont:.

As you can see, they use the same pattern for extending the drawing behaviour of the NSString.